# Website returning 404 and not 403 for forbidden pages

Tags: 8, users, debugging

My site is returning a 404 error for users who have tried to access a restricted page. I understand that this can be seen as a useful security features, however, I would like to return a 403 error instead.

I note that drupal is recording "access denied" in the logs, but somehow this is getting converted to a 404 for the user.

I have tried changing theme to see if that helps, and had no success. I have also removed custom 404 and 403 pages but this did not help either.

Googling the problem found the following file, drupal/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Controller/ExceptionController.php. This does not seem to exist in my installation of drupal.

I am not confident (or competent!) at altering php files.

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated, as I am at a loss on how to proceed.

Comment: Which pages return 404? Is this on a fresh drupal install or what steps you need to reproduce this?

Comment: This is on all pages with access requirements. Either pages restricted to certain roles, or Group pages for non-group members. 404s are returned when the user does not have the required access rights for those pages. This is not a fresh install, I have several modules running - all from the drupal modules portal. No custom modules.

Comment: Then this is probably a (unwanted) feature of a module you've installed. You can look in the module configuration if you can switch it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround using the "redirect 403 to login" module. It is not yet in alpha for D8, but seems pretty stable.